# I am having a trouble login in to this simple MEAN app

Tags: node.js, angular, authentication, jwt, mean-stack

I'm trying to build this simple MEAN stack app with the simple functionality of registering, login in and then viewing the profile.

So, where does the error occur? It pops up when this newbie coder tries to log in to this simple app

Here's a screenshot of it

[image]

Here are the codes for you to see the errors that I might have made.

This is the code belonging to the login component

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { map, subscribeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  username: String;
  password: String;

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
    private flashMessage: FlashMessagesService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onLoginSubmit() {

    console.log(this.username, this.password);

    const user = {

      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {

      console.log(data);



      if (data) {



        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);


        this.flashMessage.show('You are now logged in', {
          cssClass: 'alert-success',
          timeout: 5000
        });


        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

      }
      else {

        this.flashMessage.show('incorrect information you stupidass', {
          cssClass: 'alert-danger',
          timeout: 5000
        });

        this.router.navigate(['/login']);

      }




    });
  }

}
```

The next one is of the authentication service file

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {



  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  registerUser(user: { name: String; email: String; username: String; password: String; }) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    //adding a value to the header and connecting to the backend
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, { headers: headers }).pipe(map((res: { json: any; }) => res.json));


  }


  authenticateUser(user: { username: String; password: String; }) {

    let headers = new Headers();
    //adding a value to the header and connecting to the backend
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, { headers: headers }).pipe(map((res: { json: any; }) => res.json));

  }


  getProfile() {

    let headers = new Headers();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authroization', this.authToken);
    //adding a value to the header and connecting to the backend
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', { headers: headers }).pipe(map((res: { json: any; }) => res.json));


  }

  storeUserData(token, user) {

    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));

    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;

  }

  loadToken() {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  loggedIn() {

    return tokenNotExpired(null, localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
  }


  logout() {

    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }

}
//this.myObservable().pipe(map(data => {}))
```

And this last one is of the app.component file

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './components/register/register.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { ProfileComponent } from './components/profile/profile.component';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { ValidateService } from './services/Validate.service';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guard';

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}

const appRoutes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:4000'],
        blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:4000/api/auth']
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [ValidateService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Why does this error occur?

Edit: Below are the screenshot of postman requests that I did for this app. There you can find the value of the token as well.

The authentication request is what you see here:

[image: authentication]

This next one is for the get request done to get into the profile:

[image: profile]

Comment: You can refer these links.
1. https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/issues/335
2. https://community.auth0.com/t/what-does-jwt-must-have-3-parts-mean/7228/2

Comment: *`headers.append('Authroization', this.authToken);`*  -> **`Authorization`**

Comment: @HimanshuShekhar They really didn't help me Himanshu

Comment: @jps Do you mean in the authorization service file?

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess yes, in  `getProfile() `

Comment: @jps Only in getProfile? What about in other functions? I'll add the changes and see if it works! Thank You jps

Comment: What do you mean with 'in other functions' ? I mean the typo in the word `Authorization` and I spotted it only one time. If you have more places with the same typo, fix it everywhere of course!

Comment: @jps Other functions means the other set of function we have here in the auth.service. The registerUser() function, authenticateUser(). I am newbie! I am not used to this lingo!

Comment: @jps Those changes did nothing! Same as usual! The same error

Comment: It was not meant to solve all problems, it's just a typo I found. And if the heder name is wrong, the backend can't find it. And how does your token look like? And usually the Authorization should contain the word "Bearer", e.g. `Authorization: Bearer eyJ......`, so the code for this should be headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authToken);`

Comment: @jps Well, the token doesn't have a BEARER thing. I'll upload a screenshot of it

Comment: @jps so the code for this should be headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.authToken); < === Is this ONLY for the getProfile() one? Btw, I added those postman requests into the original post.

Comment: @halfer do you have any solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211777/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-jps).